# How to use $.post with django?

Tags: django, jquery, django-csrf

How can I use the `jquery.post()` method in Django?

This is what I am trying to do:

```
         var postdata={
              'username':$('#login-email').val(), 
              'password':$('#login-password').val()
         }

         $.post('/login/',postdata)
```

How do I CSRF protect this in django? Is there a way to add to the CSRF token to the post data?

Comment: I think you really mean to ask "How do I submit AJAX requests in Python", right? There's no "jquery.Post()" method in any other language or framework other than jquery. You're asking for the equivalent operation, correct?

Comment: @Mike I believe he's asking how to use jQuery to POST data *to* Django, I'll edit the title (again) to make it more clear

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I usually refer a file with this content to every page I want to be able to make AJAX requests:

```
if (!$)
    var $ = django.jQuery;

$('html').ajaxSend(function(event, xhr, settings) {
    function getCookie(name) {
        var cookieValue = null;
        if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
            var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                var cookie = $.trim(cookies[i]);
                // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                    cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return cookieValue;
    }
    if (!(/^http:.*/.test(settings.url) || /^https:.*/.test(settings.url))) {
        // Only send the token to relative URLs i.e. locally.
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", getCookie('csrftoken'));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 34):

Yes. I believe it's stored in `{{ csrf_token }}`. So, just do

```
     var postdata={
          'username':$('#login-email').val(), 
          'password':$('#login-password').val(),
          'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'
     }
```

You might have to double check the names, but that should be right.

Comment: Its actually `{% csrf_token %}` otherwise this is by far the best solution.

Comment: Whoops I meant `{{ csrf_token }}` the other variation is the hidden form field variant! sorry for confusing the topic :)

Comment: 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}' worked for me, on Django-1.3

Comment: me as well, on 1.3 it seems it has to be csrfmiddlewaretoken

Answer (score 5):

Although you didn't provide your html in your example is it safe to assume that you are using a `<form>`? If so, add your CSRF token template tag to your form and call `.serialize()` on your form.

Answer (score 0):

The `contrib` module in Django [has a CSRF module](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/) that you can use.

As to your question how to send a `POST`, as long as you have the URL mapped properly requests will get sent to it.  You can handle a `POST` request specifically by checking `request.POST` on the request object.

Comment: I specifically was talking about the $.post method. The reason I asked this question is that I did not want to have to deal with such a cumbersome script.