# Unable to jQuery $.post data to a view in django due to CSRF

Tags: django, post, django-csrf, csrf-protection

Before posting this i've tried every solution method posted online, including solutions on Stackoverflow and Django. (I think the reason for error perhaps is due to the fact that i'm on a newer verison of jQuery and django and most solutions are dated, using jQuery 1.9 and django 1.5.1)

Here are some URL's to solutions that don't work:

[Django CSRF check failing with an Ajax POST request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100539/django-csrf-check-failing-with-an-ajax-post-request)

[How to use $.post with django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5407463/how-to-use-post-with-django)

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax

Any help would be appreciated. Another possibility for error is the fact that i'm not actually sure where to place these snippets exactly. So far i've pasted everything inside the jquery on document load, i've also tried pasting the code in the very start of the .js file. (My javascript code is fragmented in chunks, some are seperate .js files and some are inline with the html being rendered with django context, so any solutions with "{{ csrftoken }}" are bad.

Thanks!!

Comment: Did you also try putting `{% csrf_token %}` in your `index.html`?

Comment: No, I thought for jQuery ajax/post events that was not necessary? Does {% csrf_token %} need to be placed in some arbitrary location in every .html file where any POST code will be placed? What if the POST code is in a standalone static .js file? Then it won't even be rendered with django's context.

Comment: The CSRF token only gets set if it's present in the template or if the view is decorated with `ensure_csrf_cookie()`. Putting it in `index.html` will make it apply for all your pages.

Comment: dan, post ur comment as an answer so I can mark it as correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CSRF token only gets set if it's present in the template or if the view is decorated with `ensure_csrf_cookie()`. Putting `{% csrf_token %}` in `index.html` will make it apply for all your pages.

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax):

> The CSRF token is also present in the DOM, but only if explicitly included using csrf_token in a template.

...

> If your view is not rendering a template containing the csrf_token template tag, Django might not set the CSRF token cookie. This is common in cases where forms are dynamically added to the page. To address this case, Django provides a view decorator which forces setting of the cookie: ensure_csrf_cookie().

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '{% url "some_url_which_accepts_post" %}',
            data: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{csrf_token}}', 'comment_id':1},
            success: function(data, textStatus){
                //something
            },  
        });
```